# PHP classes source code

Tags: php, oop

I'm on the stage of learning OOP with the help of PHP and David Powers book ([PHP Object Oriented Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210117)). I'm on the chapter 3, where he talks about using DateTime class. I'll like to see the implementation of the DateTime class in order to underatnd how OOP realy works.

1) Where/how can I find the source code of DateTime class?

2) For a beginner is useful to see the code source of such classes, or is better to stay away from the messy things at this level?

Comment: As for 2) - it might confuse you. It's implemented as procedural C code, so the OOP concepts and handling will not be obvious (without understanding of the PHP/Zend runtime).

Comment: 1) http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/date/ - you should already know that its in C though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother trying to look at the code for the built-in PHP classes; they're not written in PHP (they're in C), so it won't teach you anything about writing PHP. The code is available if you want it, but is only going to be useful if you already know C)

However there are lots of good example classes available. The [PEAR repository](http://pear.php.net/) contains loads of PHP classes which can be good for learning. You might also want to download some of the examples in the appropriately named [PHPClasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/).

Comment: Em. The last link is not a good resource for learning good coding practices. *Any* other example please.

Comment: @mario - that's why I gave two links. And granted phpclasses is not the best, but I've found a few good bits and pieces there. Plus, I can't think of anything else that's better, off the top of my head. (I know there are some, but I haven't got any links handy)

Answer (score 1):

> For a beginner is useful to see the
>   code source of such classes, or is
>   better to stay away from the messy
>   things at this level?

OOP is not about single classes... You have to learn how to make structures from classes by using design patterns. By the way; php is not the best language to learn oo programming.

Answer (score 0):

1. [The PHP svn repo](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/) (assuming that you're talking about the `DateTime` class in the PHP standard library)
2. It can't hurt. Even if you don't get it, you'll at worst learn nothing and at best learn a lot about OOP. So go ahead, look at source as much as possible, it rarely hurts.

It's possible (actually likely) that `DateTime` is written in C, not PHP, in which case you won't get anything out of reading it (unless you want to learn C).

Comment: It's not even likely. It's certain.